# PHP TCPDF - multiple pdf support?

Tags: tcpdf

I need to create 2 pdf file in sequence.

The version of environment 
Apache Version  2.4.25
PHP Version 5.3.29
TCPDF Version: 6.0.008

but the system intermittent produce errors:

mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  fopen(/home/fsmasor/public_html/administrator/components/com_members/library/e_cert/) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Is a directory in /home/fsmasor/public_html/administrator/components/com_events/tcpdf/tcpdf.php on line 7651

Thanks...

Source file link:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/przk8z36hlfpbnu/generate_member_receipt.php?dl=0

Comment: Please include the code producing the error

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/przk8z36hlfpbnu/generate_member_receipt.php?dl=0..